# Python 2.7 rtsp stream and "INVALID EU golomb code" Jetson TX2

Tags: python, opencv, h.264, rtsp

I'm fighting with Chinese IP camera modules, one of them has chipset IMX322 and has 2MPX. I managed to connect to this camera (there was no doc. how to do it ) but url above seems to work :

```
rtsp://<local_ip>/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp
```

I use standard python loop to get data, but there is some problem and I'm really not sure where, it can be problem with camera (wrong header) or library under Nvidia Jetson TX2 and Ubuntu 16.4.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
import cv2 
import time


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://192.168.1.11/user=admin&password=&channel=0&stream=0.sdp?tpc') 

while(True): 
    ret, frame = cap.read() 

    if ret:
        cv2.imshow("Image", cv2.resize(frame,(800,600)))        

    else:
        print('no video')
        #cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)    

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

The problem is that I'm getting unexpected behavior of VideoCapture(), it takes about 2 seconds to generate output frame in imgShow, but before that I'm receiving errors in command line level 2,3 times.

```
Invalid UE golomb code
Invalid UE golomb code
```

During extraction of correct frames from camera errors are still showing with frequency 1,2 per second. I tried to find any useful information in google but it looks like 90% of post are related with C++ or FFMPEG.